# Flutter app working when building release-APK but not when provided via Google Play Store

Tags: flutter, connection, release

We have an app connected to the internet.

Building a release APK is working and the app is connected to the internet.
Building a App Bundle, uploading it in the Google Play store and

- installing it via Google Play the app is running but gets no connection to the internet.
- downloading the apk via the App Bundle Explorer in the Google Play Console the app is running but gets no connection to the internet.

I also see the android.permission.INTERNET is set...

What can be the problem in my case?

Answer (score 0):

```
<application android:label="APP_NAME" android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" //Add This>
</application>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> //Add This
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I found out the problem is not about the connection to the internet itself - the problem seems to be inside the flutter_secure_storage - but only when deployed in Google Play Store...

After updating flutter_secure_storage to the latest version the problem was gone.

Comment: I'm facing with this problem but your solution can't help me

Answer (score 0):

Few Options I can think of:-

```
1. Build the apk from aab you uploaded on play. (test its behaviour)
2. Check that the flavor you are building, it doesn’t override settings, by having its own manifest.
3. Test on different devices.
4. See if there are any certificates installed.
5. Reverse Engineering (Last Option)
```

Answer (score 0):

### 10/2022

Hi guys, I faced with this error and the real problem came from **flutter_secure_storage** and **shared_preferences**. You guys need to add:

`android:allowBackup="false" android:fullBackupContent="false"`
to **Androidmanifest.xml** like this [issues](https://github.com/mogol/flutter_secure_storage/issues/43)!

Answer (score -1):

There is a manifest file in this directory

> android/app/src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml

Copy the internet permission from above directory and to add the internet permission in this directory

> android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: As I wrote the app is working when I build it in release mode and the permission is set and <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> already present in android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml.